# Ubuntu 14.04 - NVIDIA driver from website fails and apt-get drivers will not install

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm trying to run some `openCV cuda` enabled pre-built examples. When I them run I get:

```
what():  /home/willem/opencv/modules/core/src/cuda_info.cpp:84: error: (-217) CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version in function getDevice
```

So I've been trying to update my NVIDIA drivers for the last 2 days. I've installed the correct binaries for my system (Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit) I can't get past the login screen once they are installed. I've tried installing them through apt-get: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-364 : Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

- I've tried fixing this by making my `apt-get update` from the main server.
- I've tried auto-cleaning and restructuring my entire packaging system many times.
- I've tried installing `nvidia-364` with my synaptic package manager but it just says that one of the packages is broken and I can't uninstall it or fix whatever the broken package is under the broken menu.

Any ideas?

Comment: You say you have a 64 bit system, but the complaint is about 32 bit libraries -- a wrong version somewhere?